# Functional programming: How can I properly combine a member extraction operator?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

One feature in JavaScript seems to enable me to dodge the "right" way.

Rather than writing `d.foo` and `d.bar` one is also able to write `d["foo"]` and `d["bar"]`.

In most usage scenarios either form is all right, but in the following code

```
function f(myscale, foo_or_bar) {
    blah.attr(myscale(d => d[foo_or_bar]));
}
f(foo_scale, "foo");
f(bar_scale, "bar");
```

I am able to send a string to signal that one or the other member should be accessed.

Of course here I have only one statement (`blah.attr`), which does not warrant defining/using a function, but in practice it's more substantial and does warrant a common definition.

Indeed the code above seems so bad that it would not be much worse to send a Boolean flag `is_it_foo` and to write an `if` statement to choose between `d.foo` and `d.bar`.

What is the correct (functional programming) way for combining the two lines

```
blah.attr(foo_scale(d => d.foo));
blah.attr(bar_scale(d => d.bar));
```

into one?

(I have seen the trick of sending a function while exchanging its two parameters; but as you can tell from the question, I have not yet grasped the technique in the wild, nor perhaps even in theory.)

**Update**

I am basically seeking a **Lisp** or **Scheme** expert, who then picked up JavaScript. For this person the question will be a trivial and instantaneous exercise. If, like me, your gravity is still in the C++/Java world, please wait with me for someone to shed light. (To the 'close' voters, I'll happily delete the question if the Scheme/Lisp folks also indicate that there is no point to the question and that passing a string to extract a member is perfectly all right.)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with accessing object properties with computed strings.

Comment: Arbitrary `f`, undefined `.blah`, undefined, `.attr`, undefined `foo_scale` and `bar_scale`... Until you share actual code and the context around it, we can only guess or assume your goal. Fwiw, JavaScript and Scheme are my and your intentions are completely unclear to me. *"Combine the two lines ... into one"* - maybe show the Scheme equivalent of what you're trying to do? As it's written in your post, `bar.attr` relies on a side effect because you are not using its return value for anything - this on it's own is already unlike Scheme, which embraces functional style.

Comment: In other words, please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What is the input to your intended program? What is the expected output?

Comment: To add, your question is off-putting to proficient JavaScript and Scheme programmers alike. To the first group, it says your interested in an answer from another group. To the second group, if they don't understand your question, they must not be an expert in their group -- Each language has its own idioms and best practices and you've already admitted to being new to JavaScript; so why do you think you know what the answer is or who it should come from?

Comment: There is no Scheme or Lisp present in your question. The tags you added in an edit will be removed as you're only using them to broadcast your question to a broader audience -- Even the `functional-programming` tag is debatable as no functional styles or disciplines are observed in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing the property name as a string, you might as well pass a property getter function as an argument to `f`:

```
function f(myscale, get) {
    blah.attr(myscale(get));
}
f(foo_scale, d => d.foo);
f(bar_scale, d => d.bar);
```

Comment: Bingo.. but now you're sending _two_ parameters. How do you combine them?

Comment: @Calaf I thought the `scale` parameter was irrelevant to the question. Of course you could combine them into an object (not very functional), but there's nothing wrong with having two parameters. In this particular usage, you could of course simply do `f(foo_scale(d => d.foo))` and `f(bar_scale(d => d.bar))` with `f = blah.attr`, but I think you will need to post your complete code so that I can judge appropriately. (And where do `foo_scale` and `bar_scale` come from, are property names involved with them already?)

Comment: The code in the question was a bit too brief. Likely `d` itself also needs to be sent, depending on the context. Regardless, an accessor function is the right idea.

Answer (score 0):

For every key `foo` if you have a unique mapper function `foo_scale`, then the way your are doing currently, is the right way to go:

```
blah.attr(foo_scale(d => d.foo);
blah.attr(bar_scale(d => d.bar);
```

This is more of a code design pattern rather than a Javascript feature. As this will not only reinforce code readability but also enable you to change the function of any key at will.

But say all your keys map to a single mapper function `scale`, you could do:

```
const keys = ["foo", "bar"]

keys.forEach((key) => {
    blah.attr1(scale(d => d[foo_or_bar]);
    blah.attr2(scale2(d => d[foo_or_bar]);
    blah.attr3(scale3(d => d[foo_or_bar]);
})
```

Ideally this is a good pattern and this can be used if you are able to generalise the common patterns into a single method `scale`

Comment: Consider that `blah.attr` is the place holder for thirty lines of code. After getting done with `foo`, you copy and paste the thirty lines, modifying the right `foo`s for `bar`s, but then you stop. You know that it will be a major headache to maintain the sixty lines of code, hence the question.

Comment: But does `bar ` have a different `bar_scale` method similar to how `foo` has `foo_scale` ?

Comment: If so, then it would not scale well. Suppose you have 100 keys with each having its own `key_scale` method, then either each key has a very different purpose, or there is something wrong in logic abstraction.

Comment: Suppose all keys can go through the same transformer, then my above second snippet should work fine. Instead of the 3 lines, paste your 30 lines. It will loop over for all the keys.